# How to return HTTP 404

Tags: asp.net-core

I am building an asp.net core Web API and I need to be able to hide some of the actions in a controller.

I use the following code to return HTTP 404 (Not Found):

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    if(!_isEnabled)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
```

However, in my browser I get this result:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4",
    "title": "Not Found",
    "status": 404,
    "traceId": "00-502319d62a6027718d2ee2cb3c9f263f-28de7bfdfb48f2d8-00"
}
```

I need to make the call as if the controller does not exists and the browser shows this:

[image]

How can a Controller returns a "real" HTTP 404 experience as if the controller dos not exists at that route?

**Update 1**

The answers return a JSON data and response code 404.

I am trying to do something different.

I am trying to hide the controller as if it doesn't exist for security reasons. I like the end user browser see above screenshot (Edge in my example)

**Update 2**

I changed to the following code:

```
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    if(!_isEnabled)
    {
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound); 
    }
```

and the controller returns the following result:

```
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4","title":"Not Found","status":404,"traceId":"00-3275026575270e11a4b1a5ab0817776a-a4777e626460faeb-00"}
```

The behavior is strange. Is it a new feature in aspnet code 6 ?

****Update 3****

Here is my middleware setup in the `Program.c`. It is plain oob setup:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
    builder.Logging.AddConsole();
    builder.Logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

    builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
        

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();


    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
}
```

Comment: You can do like this `[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)`

Comment: Hi, Allen, did you had the chance to try the solution? Let me know if you need any further assistance on it.

Comment: What is `!_isEnabled`? Share the details of it. If my first solution works, we can investigate the strange issue in another thread do you agree with me? So that it can be a unique repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution For Update 1:**

Middleware could  be your savior here thus can be achived what you are trying to implement.

**Controller:**

```cs
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
        public IActionResult GetById(int id)
        {
         
           // return Ok(NotFound());
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound);
        }
```

**Note:** You can choose either of the status pattern.

**Middleware:**

```cs
public class CustomResponseMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
       
        public CustomResponseMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (httpContext.Response.StatusCode == 404)
            {
                httpContext.Response.Redirect("/WrongControllerName/WrongAction");
            }
            await _next(httpContext);
        }

    }
```

**Note:** As you can see, we are checking the controller `status code` and checking if any `404` decteced. Once the desired `status code` we will redirect a controller which doesn't exist at all that eventually generate the expected output.

**Register Middleware In Program.cs:**

```cs
app.UseMiddleware<CustomResponseMiddleware>();
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for response. Please see my Update 1.

Comment: Well, got your requirement, wait a while, lot of soltuions can be implemented to achieve that.

Comment: Hi @AllanXu, could you please try the solution now? This is one of the elegant way you can implement that.

Comment: Please see the update #2

Comment: Which tool do you use to create the gif anim?

Comment: Would you kindly share your other relevant `code snippet`? For instance, your middleware, `program.cs` etc. Importantly, first, ensure the given solution you have implemented accordingly. For additional issue its wiser to create new post so make the stackoverflow question unique.

Comment: Another point, middleware order is also crucial here. Please share how did you placed your middleware and where?

Comment: Just added my program.cs. Thank you for help.

Comment: I appreciate the response and help. But adding a middleware that intercepts 404 and redirects to non-exiting controller seems like a workaround but not a proper solution. If I mark it as answer, it might mislead others.

Comment: Then how you can [`display this page`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTCbH.png)? Because if you redirect to the page exists will display that controller details. Therefore, if you would still [`want to show this output`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTCbH.png), I think my solution is elegant. No matter you if you don't accept the answer.

Comment: The page you are referring is returned by kestrel when there is no route is defined for a URL path. The intent of this question is  how to prevent a particular controller return a JSON data along with the 404 status. I expect such an approach exists. Adding a new custom Middleware impacts all http request/responses for all controllers. This is such a basic requirement and there should be an simpler solution for it.

Comment: I think there is a different between data not found in REST API servicer and page not found in web page server.  I am looking for a way for controller return exactly what a webserver (like kestrel) returns when a page not found.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for future visitors, this will set the response body to null (and the browser will treat it as a 404):

```
return NotFound(null);
```